# Dynamically creating a force directed graph with weighting

Tags: graph, visualization

I can't find any way to draw a force directed graph where the weighting of the edges affects their length.

Although the Neato layout engine for .Dot format claims to do this, it never seems to actually respond to the edge weight that I give to it.

Ideally, I'd like to do this in Javascript. I've been using the Javascript Infovis Toolkit, but this doesn't seem to have any means for setting a weighting.

Any suggestions gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So infovis doesn't solve this problem at all well, and I can't see what's going on with gvis either. However, I have solved this problem using cytoscape.

Although I haven't used it, cytoscape does have a command line option, so you could potentially use it to create images dynamically.